# Custom script "invoked too many times" error

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

Credit: [Google Spreadsheets function to find distance between cities](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16757/)

```
function getDirection(city1, city2, unit) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(city1).setDestination(city2)
    .setMode(Maps.DirectionFinder.Mode.DRIVING)
    .getDirections();
  var d = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;

  var distance, value = d.split(" ")[0].replace(",", ""), text = d.split(" ")[1];
  if(text == unit) {
    distance = value;
  } else if(text == "km" && unit == "mi") {
    distance = value / 1.6;
  } else {
    distance = value * 1.6;
  }
  return Math.round(distance);
}
```

I have used this code snippet in one of my sheets. I am working on a dataset with roughly 6000 entries and I am getting some errors because of the large volume.

> Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account. (line 0).
>
> Service invoked too many times for one day: route. (line 4).

I considered purchasing a Google Apps business account to increase my quota, but that might not even help. Do you maybe have any advice for me in this regard?

Comment: Posible duplicate of http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47537/how-to-avoid-invoked-too-many-times-per-second-error

Comment: @Rubén See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages and you will see that this is not related to the post you mention.

Comment: @Jacob I don't see that at this time. Are you considering the google apps limits the core of the question?

Answer (score 3):

<s>Instead of using a Google Sheet's custom functions, consider to use [Fusion Tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2571232?hl=en).</s>

Also could be helpful to read [Map your data with the Maps API and Fusion Tables - Google Geo Developers Blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2010/05/map-your-data-with-maps-api-and-fusion.html)

Why? or regarding errors, Google Sheet's custom functions, purchasing a Google Apps for Work account...

From [Quotas for Google Services - Apps Script - Google Develpers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages)

> *Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account.* This indicates that the script began executing too many
> times in a short period. It most commonly occurs for custom functions
> that are called repeatedly in a single spreadsheet. To avoid this
> error, code your custom functions so that they only need to be called
> once per range of data, as explained in the [guide to custom
> functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions).

From "guide to custom functions" [Custom Functions in Google Sheets - Apps Script - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

> #### Optimization
>
> Each time a custom function is used in a spreadsheet, Google Sheets
> makes a separate call to the Apps Script server. If your spreadsheet
> contains dozens (or hundreds, or thousands!) of custom function calls,
> this process can be quite slow.

Pay special attention to the following excerpt from the same previous referred source

> Consequently, if you plan to use a custom function multiple times on a
> large range of data, consider modifying the function so that it
> accepts a range as input in the form of a two-dimensional array, then
> returns a two-dimensional array that can overflow into the appropriate
> cells.

Again from [Quotas for Google Services - Apps Script - Google Develpers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#exception_messages) (just replace Calendar by route)

> *Service invoked too many times*: *Calendar*. This indicates that the script called the given service too many times in one day.

Comment: FWIW, Fusion Tables was deprecated in 2019. Among other offerings, Google are [recommending](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9551050?hl=en)  [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) and [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs), [Google Maps Platform](https://mapsplatform.google.com/) and (depending on your needs) [Data Studio](https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/data-studio/). None of these services is free.